# It is alright to include students' first names in a teaching statement?

Tags: faculty-application, personal-name, privacy, teaching-statement

Is it alright to include students' first names in a teaching statement, or would this come off as weird and too personal? Or a privacy concern?

You often hear the advice to include specific stories that exemplify some of the things you claim about yourself in your teaching statement. I've got an anecdote involving two students I want to tell. My thought is that including their names will demonstrate that this wasn't just some frivolous incident that I'm talking up; that I honestly got to know these students. Also, I think the story would read more clearly if I can give them names rather than pronouns.

Comment: Do you have a way to ask their permission?

Comment: @Buffy Yeah, I could probably dig up their email addresses. Then I've just got to hope they still check (or forward) their university email.

Comment: What country are you in? Conventions for using formal vs informal names, and whether first names are considered formal enough, vary widely by country. (Having said that, it's a law of the internet that if people don't say where they are from, and don't understand that other countries are different, then they're probably American, and someone who says in their profile that they are from "UC Riverside" without saying where in the world that is is almost certainly American.)

Comment: @MichaelKay Well, it does also say I'm from California on my profile. ;)

Comment: @MichaelKay But also, I'm not just interested in the answer to this question for American schools. What if I'm applying to university jobs outside the US, and I want to know if this would be unusual there? If there is a strikingly different convention in a certain country or region, I'd like to know. Also in general this question isn't just for me, but for every future visitor of the site who has the same question, wherever they may be from.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to answer the question for my own country (the UK) without understanding better what you mean by a "teaching statement" (more particularly, who gets to read it, do they know the students, etc). And I certainly wouldn't be able to answer it for any other country (the notion that everyone outside the US is "international" is a common American fallacy).

Comment: @MichaelKay Your comment suggests that "teaching statements" aren't necessarily a usual part of a university job application outside the US. Is this so? Just to establish what it is from my perspective, when applying to university teaching jobs (in the US at least) that require teaching duties, part of the application is to submit a "teaching statement" or "teaching philosophy". It's usually a 1-2 page essay on what/how/why you teach, and different universities weight it differently among your application materials.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you should avoid giving their full names, as opposed to just their first names unless they give permission for it. Better, using an alias for the students protects their privacy but doesn't cost you any thing in the telling of the stories. Alice and Bob, as usual.

But some readers might actually wonder whether you were *too* personal with the students, not keeping a proper "academic distance". I often tell a story about two students who succeeded after failure. It is a great story, and it works without names. If they heard my story they would recognize themselves, I think. But no one else would. Not even their classmates at the time.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to use aliases, and I'd add that you might say, in parentheses or in a footnote, something like "the names are fictitious but the students are real."

Comment: @AndreasBlass "The names have been changed to protect the innocent" :-)

Comment: When I need aliases, I always use the published list of [hurricane names from NOAA](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/aboutnames.shtml). It alternates male/female and there are six cycles through the alphabet worth of names. Plenty of variety without a whole lot of effort.

Comment: I like the NOAA one.  I tend to go with Muppets or Looney Tunes characters -- that can give a quick image of the student's personality, and yet it's clearly fake.   (My use case is showing students samples of how  in prior years, students had done self-assessment or team-assessment type of tasks, complete with my feedback.  I try to show an excellent one, a pretty good one, and one that's barely acceptable, so they can understand the range of potential responses.  Since these are personality-based in part, obvious pseudonyms help.)

Answer (score 5):

I would just use made-up names, made obvious by using scarequotes on the first usage.  Personally, I feel Alice and Bob is a little too generic (like a math problem).

I would probably choose two from Renee, Sophia, Marcos, and Hans.  Names with some interesting oomph to them.  I would keep the sex the same.  Not because gender is a part of the story (well I doubt it is).  But just you will have an easier time picturing the students in your mind and writing about them if you don't change the gender. Or possibly referring to them on the spot during an interview (no pronoun slips).

Comment: Or keep the initial of each name the same: Jeremy -> Jacob, Helen -> Harriet, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily use alphabetically-sequential names, as we use in logic problems, communications, and so on. Typically this starts "Alice, Bob, Charlie", but you may wish to vary this for your paper if student gender is important.

The sequence of names often also uses "Eve" in communications and cryptography, as an "eavesdropper". It would probably be more appropriate to change this for your paper

Comment: The asker is writing a teaching statement for a job application, not a research paper.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Why should that matter?  The names "Alice" and "Bob" are not highly technical concepts which can only be understood by experts. :)  Weather system names follow the same concept of sequentially-initialled first names too.  Given that we have this existing scheme which is familiar to anyone who's ever heard a weather forecast, and which is used in all technical areas where applying names for actors can help comprehension, it would seem strange *not* to use it.  And the very fact that all names are alphabetically-sequential tells readers implicitly that this scheme is being used.

Comment: Your answer twice says "your paper", which clearly indicates that you're giving advice about how to write a paper. Advice on how to write a paper is not necessarily applicable to writing personal teaching statements (e.g., I would always use "I" in the latter, but probably never a paper) so, at the very least, you should edit your answer to make it obvious that you do intend your advice to apply to teaching statements.

Comment: Personally, I find that using Alice, Bob, and so on, in sequence, looks highly contrived, which detracts from the message a personal statement is supposed to convey. In a research paper, that artificiality doesn't matter at all but, in a teaching statement, it looks insincere to me.